# DB2 Temp Table - Retrieving inserted Data in DB2 Z OS

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I have created a temp table and Inserted in DB2 ZOS as mentioned below

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2 (col1 INT)   

INSERT INTO tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10687);    
INSERT INTO tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10689);    
INSERT INTO tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10691);
```

Inserted data with out any issues, where I'm trying to retrieve the data using select query Im unable see any values which I had inserted with the above values and getting.

```
select * from tmp2
```

I have an earlier experience in SQL Server and ran the below queries  which work without any issues.

```
Drop table #tmp2    
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (col1 INT)    

INSERT INTO #tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10687);    
INSERT INTO #tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10689);   
INSERT INTO #tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10691);   
select * from #tmp2
```

How to get to see the inserted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies.

Below is the set of queries, actually I was looking for

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.tmp2 (col1 INTEGER) 
CCSID EBCDIC ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO SESSION.tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10687);    
INSERT INTO SESSION.tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10689);    
INSERT INTO SESSION.tmp2 (col1) VALUES (10691);

select * from SESSION.tmp2;
```

Comment: This code works,  I just successfully ran it in SPUFI so 2 questions.  What's the sqlcode you get for the DECLARE of the table and is the SELECT in the the same process as the declaration?   SESSION is the thread,  not the job or unit of work.

Comment: I ran those scripts were in AQT tool. Here Select statement is not part of the declaration, just I used here to display the values which I have inserted in temp table (tmp2).

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createglobaltemptable.html) for details, sometimes this is faster than waiting for an answer.

The CGTT (create global temporary table) object differs from a regular table when a COMMIT happens - it will empty the table if there are no `with hold` cursors open on the table. If you have **autocommit** enabled for your database connection then the result will be that your CGTT table may appear to be empty.

If you want more control over the commit behaviour (and rollback behaviour, and logging options etc. ) you can consider using DGTT ([declare global temporary table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declareglobaltemptable.html)) instead because that syntax lets you use additional non-default options like `on commit preserve rows` and `on rollback preserve rows`. But a DGTT object has more restrictions , including that its qualifier must always be `SESSION` and its definition is not catalogued so the table is invisible to any other session.